# Access user fields?

Tags: users, 8

`$account = \Drupal::currentUser()` loads the user object into `$account`, but how do I access custom fields I've created on the user object (via the admin UI)?

With `dpm($account)` I can't see any of my custom fields.

Comment: Do the custom fields have any values yet? Seem to remember them being missing from the entity object until they actually have a value set

Comment: Yes, they have values. I can get the uid with `\Drupal::currentUser()->id()` and then do a database query, but in D7 they were there on the object already?

Comment: This issue isn't just about the currant user; it pertains generally to the user object. 

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.2.x gets you halfway there, but as is usually the case with Drupal Docs, it leaves much still in the dark

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`\Drupal::currentUser()` returns an `Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface` object. That could be a full user (that would be a `Drupal\user\UserInterface`), but right now, for the default authentication method, it is not.

Use this to get the user entity and all the fields:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())
```

D7 had exactly the same behavior, the difference now is just that in D7, they were simply different stdClass'es, now you have explicit interfaces to differentiate the two.

Comment: Despite the down-vote, this answer is correct, even about Drupal 7. `$GLOBALS['user']` doesn't contain a full loaded user object, in Drupal 7; it contains only the information found in the users table.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why this got a downvote.  It is correct, both about D7 and D8.

Comment: This is only part of the answer. And in fact, it gets you no closer to the data than the original "solution".   You have to "get" the data from the object. To do that - see the working solution posted by @batigolix below.

Comment: Note that fields that don't have values will not appear in the values array.

Comment: Does this mean that when I have a method which takes an `AccountInterface $account` as argument to load a full user from could also be passed an already fully loaded `Drupal\user\Entity\User` object? And then inside this method I simply check the instance of what I got to prevent an unnecessary `$this->userStorage->load($account->id())`?

Comment: It could be, yes. That said, user entities are statically cached, so that call should be very fast in almost all cases.

Answer (score 25):

And here is how to get it out of that object:

```
// Load the current user.
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

// Get field data from that user.
$website = $user->get('field_website')->value;
$body = $user->get('body')->value;

// Some default getters include.
$email = $user->get('mail')->value;
$name = $user->get('name')->value;
$uid= $user->get('uid')->value;
```

Comment: You get the user ID with `$user->id()`.

Comment: Also, the User entity doesn't have a *body* base field. If that is a field added from the user interface, the field name would start with *field_*. I would avoid that example, as it makes users think that is a base field added from Drupal core code.

Answer (score 1):

[`Drupal::currentUser()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcurrentUser/8.1.x) returns an object implementing [`Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxyInterface.php/interface/AccountProxyInterface/8.1.x). That is different from what returned from `User::load()`, which is an object implementing [`Drupal\user\UserInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserInterface.php/interface/UserInterface/8.1.x).

This means it's not assured you get a full `User` object with its fields loaded, but it's not even assured you get a `User` object. As consequence, you call call some of the methods available from the `User` class, such as `User::get()`. You can call [`AccountInterface::id()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/function/AccountInterface%3A%3Aid/8.1.x), which returns the user ID; with that, you can then load the full `User` object with `User::load()` and have access to all the fields modules attached to the entity.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$account = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

With `$account`, you can then access all the fields associated with a user account.

Comment: Perhaps, but it still begs the question: "how do you access the CUSTOM fields".  See answer above from @batigolix

Comment: The question is more _Why `$account = \Drupal::currentUser(): dpm($account);` doesn't show any custom fields?_ but this answer says how to access user entity fields. Since the question doesn't say which fields the OP is trying to access, the answer just says which method to use. There aren't answers from @batigolix.