# Load custom fields with entityQuery

Tags: users, 8, database, entities

I'm trying to load a user by it's uid via an Entity Query, this seems to work, however i'm missing my custom fields defined on the Entity User.

I'm getting all the default fields like 'username', 'email', ... but custom fields like 'field_firstname', 'field_lastname' aren't being loaded from the database.

I would like to keep using entityQuery, as the code is being reused for other entities, where the custom fields seem to load fine.

This code is being used in a module which dynamically loads entities based on mergefields used in an Email Template. If there is a mergefield `{{user.name}}` I need to dynamically load the user entity and fill in the value in the standard field `name`.

This works fine, but when using `{{user.field_firstname}}` the field `field_firstname` is not found.

This is my code:

```
$user = loadEntity('user', 'uid', $userId);

function loadEntity($entityName, $idField, $id) {
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery($entityName);
    $query->condition($idField, $id, '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    $store = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entityName);
    $id = array_shift($result);
    return empty($id) ? null : $store->load($id);
}
```

Comment: `\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load()` works as said in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146308/access-user-fields.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it somewhat generic, this code is also used for other entities, and I wouldn't want to switch on entity type to \Drupal\...\{entity}::load() my entities

Comment: The uid is the ID. You're doing a query with the UID as input to receive the UID. That's pointless. Maybe that's just an example, I don't know, but it is not relevant to your problem. Loading the user entity with the ID must load all fields, base and configuable. Also your return is strange, why return an object or an empty array? Should be NULL as fallback.

Comment: return is an error, code isn't exactly is stated above, tried to get my gist across :)

Comment: Please show the code you are really using, or the only possible answer is the one given in a comment by @Berdir, which would not be much helpful, since that is not even the code you are using. It would be like asking how to make a cheesecake New York style, and then coming out saying "but I really want to make an upside-down cake."

Comment: edited my code and explanation